# How to Stop Array Formula Messing up in Sorting in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am exporting the data through `Array(Vlookup` from different sheet by matching Id's but whenever i sort the data A to Z by using any column. ID's array formula keeps the Id as it is. Due to which data cannot be sorted.

Your help will be much appreciated.

[Sheet Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1L0f5ghbC532LXjap-PGdmdriBlYNwuaNfnxuYzf8MN4/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try in A1:

```
={"IDs"; QUERY('Data Sheet'!A2:B, "select A where A <> 0 and A is not null order by B asc")}
```

and B2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 'Data Sheet'!$A$2:$I, {2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, 0))))
```

...if you want to keep vlookup

`asc` can be changed to `desc`

Comment: Thank you @player0 for posting an answer. The problem i have been facing is i want to sort the data manually using any column. when i sort the Column A to Z-A all other data gone.